# Open QTP (UFT) Using Java Script using Chrome

Tags: javascript, qtp, hp-uft, browser-automation

The following is the code I used to launch qtp, It is working well with IE but not in chrome.
What are the changes I shd Make to open through Chrome

```
    var qtApp = new ActiveXObject("QuickTest.Application");
    qtApp.Launch(); // Start QuickTest
    qtApp.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Your question does not look complete. I feel there's more context to it. Can detail it down?

Comment: Task is to Get the data from the HTML File, When we click the submit button, file containing the data entered will be downloaded and QTP should be opened and the file downloaded should be used as the test data.

Comment: So to open UFT I have written the code , but its not opening in chrome, but it is opening in IE.. The problem is, in IE the file download is not happening

Comment: Check the version compatibility of chrome with QTP, not all versions are compatible

Comment: I am not able to lauch QTP, but when i run qtp to run on chrome, it is working..

Comment: Please have a look at the below question I have asked
Download Data From HTML File and Then Launch QTP

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's VBScript is integrated with COM and UFT also exposes a COM interface, this is why you were able to launch UFT from HTML using VBScript. However VBScript is not supported by Chrome and JavaScript is not integrated with COM (at least not Chrome's JavaScript).

Therefore I don't think there's a simple way to launch UFT from an HTML page using Chrome. It is possible if you write a Chrome Extension but I don't think this is worth the trouble.

Comment: I would also add that Chrome does not support activeX objects to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it will be to create an ASP.Net website, ASP.net will support opening UFT using the COM interfaces. I am doing the same thing for ALM's OTA API.