# Download Data from HTML file and Then Launch QTP

Tags: javascript, html, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

Task is to Get the data from the HTML File, When we click the submit button, file containing the data entered will be downloaded and QTP should be opened and the file downloaded should be used as the test data. In the following code
Case1: When I use in Chrome, File is downloaded but, QTP Not opening
Case2: When I use in IE, QTP isopenend but file not getting downloaded.

Please suggest change in code so that both will work

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
   function exportF() {
document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = 
document.getElementById("text").value;
document.getElementById("input1").innerHTML = 
document.getElementById("text1").value;
document.getElementById("input2").innerHTML = 
document.getElementById("text2").value;
var table = document.getElementById("table");
var html = table.outerHTML;

var url = 'data:application/vnd.C:\\Users\patilch\Desktop\test.xlsx,' + 
escape(html); // Set your html table into url 
var link = document.getElementById("downloadLink");
link.setAttribute("href", url);
link.setAttribute("download", "export.xls"); // Choose the file name
link.click(); // Download your excel file  


var qtApp = new ActiveXObject("QuickTest.Application");
qtApp.Launch(); // Start QuickTest
qtApp.Visible = true;
return false;
}
</script>
</head>


<body>


<div class="container">
<header>
<h1>Payment Processing</h1>
</header>
</div>



<content>
<form onsubmit="return exportF()">
 <table>
   <tr>
    <td>File Path</td>
    <td>Sap Generated Path</td>
    <td>Result</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>  <input id="text" type="text" /></td>
    <td>  <input id="text1" type="text" /></td>
    <td>  <input id="text2" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="RUN"/></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </form>

</content>
<table id="table" style="display: none">
 <tr>
 <td id="input">
 <td id="input1">
 <td id="input2">
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <a style="display: none" id="downloadLink"></a>
 </body>
 </div>
 </html>
```

Comment: You are not telling QuickTest.Application to launch with the file and you are not telling Chrome to launch QuickTest.Application since it does not run activeX

Comment: WHat changed should I make in Code

Comment: Perhaps `qtApp.Open("C:\\Users\patilch\Desktop\test.xlsx")`

Comment: I wantu launch QTP in chrome...I cannot use like u said coz Chrome doesnt support ActiveX

Comment: Then you are sol unless you can send a mine type that will let chrome open qtp

Comment: Can u help me to download data in excel from IE? as i can open QTP in IE

Comment: Sorry no. I do not use activeX

Comment: hOw can i do in chrome??? Can u plz tell me the changes i shd make in chrome to open qtp using JavaScript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open QTP (UFT) Using Java Script using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49230113/open-qtp-uft-using-java-script-using-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

another possible way is to execute a .vbs file from HTML. You can check more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044561/is-it-possible-to-run-the-vbscript-file-vbs-from-the-browser)

in your vbs file you can easily open QTP using the below code in VBS

```
Set qtpApp=CreateObject("QuickTest.Application") 
qtpApp.Launch 
qtpApp.Visible = True
```

This is a bit unorthodox method to try it, you will have to check how you can integrate with your current script